# A question about security of Facebook registration

Tags: facebook

I am planning to use Facebook registration to allow people to use their Facebook credentials to register/login to my site.

The details can be seen here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

The documentation says that when a user logs in to Facebook, Facebook will fire an onLogin event and I can use this event to login the user to my site.

My question is, if I tell my website to login the user when the event is fired, isn't it easy for an attacker to login as any user by just spoofing my javascript call ?

What is the general best practice to do in this case? Or is this thing inherently not secure?

(Or is there any other service I should be using for login/registration rather than the Facebook registration plugin)?

Comment: I think any oAuth work this way. FB auth is not an exception. oAuth is pretty safe. But session hacking by MITM attack is plausible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is very spoofable, but after you get that ping, to actually log someone in, you should use the JS SDK `FB.login()` which does a call to facebook to validate the current user's cookies which then returns you their UID and access_token.